# How to make [std::operator""s] visible in a namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, visibility, user-defined-literals

```
#include <chrono>

namespace X
{
using namespace std;
struct A
{
    std::chrono::seconds d = 0s; // ok
};
}

namespace Y
{
struct B
{
    std::chrono::seconds d = 0s; // error
};
}
```

The error message is:

> error : no matching literal operator for call to 'operator""s' with
>   argument of type 'unsigned long long' or 'const char *', and no
>   matching literal operator template
>             std::chrono::seconds d = 0s;

My question is:

I don't want to `use namespace std;` in `namespace Y`; then, how should I make `std::operator""s` visible in `namespace Y`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to have all the chrono literals then you can use

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
```

If you just want `operator""s` then you can use

```
using std::chrono_literals::operator""s;
```

Do note that at least on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) gcc issues a warning for the above line but clang does not.  To me there should be no warning.  I have asked a follow up question about this at [Should a using command issue a warning when using a reserved identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444490/should-a-using-command-issue-a-warning-when-using-a-reserved-identifier)

Comment: I think you need `using namespace ...;` for the first, the second one issue a warning on g++.

Comment: @Holt I think that is a gcc bug.  Yes it is a reserved name but we are not defining it, just using it so it should be okay.  I just added a note about that and that clang does not warn.

Comment: This is meant to be used as `using namespace std::chrono_literals;`. The `literals::` part is redundant.

Comment: @T.C. Good point.  I forgot you could drop the `literal` namespace.

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr: Use

```
using namespace std::string_literals
```

> These operators are declared in the namespace `std::literals::string_literals`, where both `literals` and `string_literals` are inline namespaces. Access to these operators can be gained with `using namespace std::literals`, `using namespace std::string_literals`, and `using namespace std::literals::string_literals`.

Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s