# Should a using command issue a warning when using a reserved identifier?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, reserved-words, using-directives, user-defined-literals

When using the line

```
using std::literals::chrono_literals::operator""s;
```

in g++ 6.3.0, the compiler issues a warning stating:

> warning: literal operator suffixes not preceded by '_' are reserved for future standardization
>
> ```
> using std::literals::chrono_literals::operator""s;
> ```

A similar warning is also issued in MSVS. However, clang 3.8.0 issues no such warning.

Since `operator""s` is defined by the standard for the chrono library shouldn't this not issue a warning since we are just importing the name and not defining one?

Comment: Warnings, unless they're mandatory diagnostics, are always a bit subjective. While I agree with you here, that just makes our a common opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Arguably, the wording is clear enough on this—[[over.literal]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.literal#1):

> Some literal suffix identifiers are
>   reserved for future standardization; see 17.6.4.3.5. A declaration **whose *literal-operator-id*** uses such a literal suffix
>   identifier is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

This can be interpreted as referring to (UDL operator) declarations whose "name" is a *literal-operator-id*—which of course excludes your case, since *literal-operator-id*s are unqualified. Same goes for [[reserved.names]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/reserved.names#2), where the “context”s are declarations of user-defined literal operators.

Comment: No declaration "directly" contains a *literal-operator-id*, by this argument. That nonterminal is only used in two places (*template-id* and *unqualified-id*).

Comment: @T.C. No, my argument was not about productions, but equivalence. The declaration does not name a *literal-operator-id*.

Comment: Well, `operator""s` *is* a *literal-operator-id*, so I'm not sure I get the argument.

Comment: @T.C. A *literal-operator-id* is never qualified.

Comment: ...so? `std::literals::chrono_literals::` is the *nested-name-specifier* in the *using-declaration* and `operator""s` is a *literal-operator-id* used as an *unqualified-id* in that *using-declaration*. (s/using-declaration/using-declarator/g as needed to account for changes by your paper.)

Comment: @T.C. "whose", to me, implies that the declaration's name *is* a *literal-operator-id*. Which coincides with the cases in which a new name is declared (and not an old one redeclared).

Comment: @T.C. Okay, the topmost nonterminal is never a *literal-operator-id*, but it can directly reduce to one. My formulation was really bad here, my bad.

Comment: For a *simple-declaration*, you'd need to go through *init-declarator* to *declarator* to *noptr-declarator* to *declarator-id* to *id-expression* to *unqualified-id* before you get to *literal-operator-id*. (And for *literal-operator-id*s in particular, they typically form a *noptr-declarator* that is itself part of a bigger *noptr-declarator* that uses the *noptr-declarator parameters-and-qualifiers* production.) For a *using-declaration* (or *-declarator*), *unqualified-id* is part of the production directly. So I'm not seeing an argument from the grammar here.

Comment: @T.C. "Directly" as in "removing no terminals". Not "directly" as in "with one production". And yeah, I do see an argument from the grammar. Of course this is all using a liberal interpretation of the wording, and clarification could be appropriate.

Comment: So, in `using foo::operator""s;`, you say dropping `foo::` is not OK even though the top-level production is "`using` `typename`(opt) *nested-name-specifier* *unqualified-id*;", but for `foo operator""s(unsigned long long);`, you say it's OK to drop the *parameters-and-qualifiers* `(unsigned long long)`, even though the top-level declarator in that declaration is the the whole `operator""s(unsigned long long)`. What am I missing, because I'm really not seeing how that argument works?

Comment: @T.C. The top-level declarator, but not the top-level name. The top-level declarator can be anything and is rather uninteresting.

Comment: "A *name* is a use of an *identifier* ([lex.name]), *operator-function-id* ([over.oper]), *literal-operator-id* ([over.literal]), *conversion-function-id* ([class.conv.fct]), or *template-id* ([temp.names]) that denotes an entity or label ([stmt.goto], [stmt.label])." ([basic]/4) That definition doesn't include *nested-name-specifier*s, so the "top-level name" can't be anything but `operator""s` in both cases.

Comment: @T.C. No, I did not mean the formally defined term... I adjusted the answer to make my point clearer, anyway.

Comment: I think you are trying too hard to read a "whose *declarator-id* is a *literal-operator-id*" into the current wording - the fact that you have to resort to a poorly-defined scary-quoted "name" is telling :) I think the answer is simply that the current wording, perhaps defectively, disallows OP's *using-declaration*.

Comment: @T.C. Sounds agreeable. I'll file an issue and see what Mike has to say.

Comment: @Columbo Any update?  I was thinking about offering a bounty to get some more attention to this.